# AJAX POST to PHP from JS is empty

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, post

index.html:

```
<script>
 function myFunction() {
        var srcd = document.getElementById("two").src;
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST", //type of method
          url: "/file.php", //your page
          data: {
            src: srcd
          }, // passing the values
          success: function(res) {
            location.reload(); 
          }
        });
      }
</script>
```

file.php:

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
$src = $_POST["src"];
$jsonString = file_get_contents('jsonFile.json');
$data = json_decode( $jsonString, true );
foreach ( $data as $key => $entry )
{
        if ( $entry['src'] == $src )
        {
                $data[$key]['counter']++;
        }
}
$newJsonString = json_encode( $data );
file_put_contents( 'jsonFile.json', $newJsonString );
?>
```

But I have realized that `$src` in PHP is null. The variable is assigned no value. I know for a fact that the POST request takes place, as if access control headers aren't present in `file.php`, an error appears in the console.

If I assign a value directly to the PHP file and run it, like `$src = 'https://someurl.com/';`, it works as expected.

How can I fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: console.log(srcd) and see if it's the value you expect.

Comment: you can right click on the webpage select `inspect` menu.in the opened tab select network.to see if you send the request right

Comment: @Matt Yes, it is the value I expect. But it isn't surrounded by double quotes, if that matters.